# Computing an Integral involving the Gauss Map.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces

I am trying to solve a geometry problem:

> Let $T$ be the torus given by rotating the circle $\{ (x,0,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | \ (x-2)^2 + z^2 = 1 \}$ around the $z$-axis and let $G : T \to S^2$ be the Gauss map.  Compute the integral $$\int_T G^* \ \eta_{S^2}$$ where $\eta_{S^2}$ is the area form on $S^2$.

My first step is to write
\begin{equation*}
\int_T G^* \ \eta_{S^2} = \int_{G(T)} \eta_{S^2} .
\end{equation*}
I am not really sure where to go from here.  Not sure if Stokes' theorem will be of any use since we don't have a boundary or a "$d$" appearing already.  Any hints or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you just need to know how many times $G(T)$ covers $S^2$. As far as I can see that is $2$ so the integral is just twice the area of $S^2$

Comment: I see that, but shouldn't this involve a little more than that?

Comment: I wrote it below explicitly

Comment: I see that now, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as a explained above the answer is $2\times {\rm Area}_{S^2}=8\pi$

More explicitly:
we can parametrize the above torus by $\phi$ and $\theta$ as
$(x,y,z)=(\cos (\theta ) \sin (\phi ),\sin (\theta ) \sin (\phi ),\cos (\phi ))$
where both angles go from $0$ to $2\pi$.

The Gauss map explicitly is
$$
\{\cos (\theta ) \sin (\phi ),\sin (\theta ) \sin (\phi ),\cos (\phi )\}\in S^2
$$
as these are usual spherical coordinates on $S^2$ (with the only difference that both angles allowed to go from $0$ to $2\pi$) we get twise the usual answer
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta |\sin\phi|=8\pi
$$